# React complex loading with multiple stages

Tags: reactjs

I have face complex loading example with React.
This is what I want to do [how it looks visually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1njBM.png)

Basically I need to load this in multiple stages.
It is not really good to do with css like elements on the bottom.
Basically I need render, get element width height, render all others.
Just spinning my head how I can do that.

It should be like render->render somehow

Comment: How is this a `reactjs` problem? And what's wrong with using css as the solution?

Comment: well it is not easy sometimes to do everything with css. For example it is hard to place element inside another element in bottom right. I would just run an javascript to calculate at least help div to fill the gap and make following element at the bottom (to make right I can use float: right).
How to run my custom javascript anyway to calculate something?
I just want to catch the idea how to make such things with React

Comment: You can generally access the DOM element and its height at `componentDidMount`, with some exceptions. That said, I'll still suggest you to use css directly. There are many styles that you can use for this case. For example, flexbox.